# To find positive roots of a quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics

Find all values of $a$ so that:

$$x^2- ax+(4a+1)= 0$$

has both roots positive.

I have been working hard and long on known facts but am unable to crack this one.
Finally saw this site and hope for some relief!

Regards,
Aditya Iyengar (Grade 9)

Comment: Could you show  your work? Do you know Bhaskara's formula?

Comment: Why don't you find the solutions using the quadratic formula. This will give you two answers, from these answers you should be able to figure out what values of $a$ make the answers positive.

Comment: The quadratic formula is: 

$$ax^2+bx+c$$ 

$$-b+-\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Comment: The quadratic formula is this one: $\dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :**

If $x_1+x_2>0$ and $x_1 \cdot x_2 >0$ then $x_1>0$ and $x_2>0$

where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are roots .

Next , use [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#Example) to get two inequalities in term of $a$ .